# C temperature conversion from Book "C programming language - The second edition"

Tags: c, temperature

Im learning C by reading the book called "C programming language - The second edition" by Brian W. Kernighan and Dennis M. Ritchie.

I dont quite get how the temperature conversion works.

This is how it looks in the book:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

int fahr, celsius;
int lower, upper, step;

upper = 300;
step = 20;
lower = 0;

fahr = lower;
while (fahr <= upper) {
    celsius = 5 * (fahr-32) / 9;
    printf("%d\t%d\n", fahr, celsius);
    fahr = fahr + step;
}
return 0;
}
```

As far as i understand the program calls and executes the functions and operations in the order the program is written in, so if i wrote it i would put the last line of code "fahr = fahr + step;" before "printf".

Can somebody explain this?

Comment: Did you run it and see what output it produces? What did you notice about the values in the output? Were they correct? Now change the code to what you think it would be. What is the difference in output with that?

Comment: Can you explain why you’d put it before the `printf`?

Comment: I did now, and i see that fahr now starts with 20 instead of 0. I still dont get it.

Comment: I imagine that since the program executes the functions and operations in the order the program is written in, that the last line of code would not be included in the calculation because printf is before it.

Comment: The last line in the loop is in preparation for the *next* `printf`. The first `printf` gets its `fahr` value from the setting of that variable outside the loop.

Comment: It not only starts at 20 then, the celsius and fahrenheit values will not correspond anymore

Comment: It might be instructive to recode this as a `for` loop (e.g.) `for (fahr = lower;  fahr <= upper;   fahr = fahr + step) { celcius = ...; printf(...); }` to see why the increment belongs at the bottom of the `while` loop

Comment: @kaylum By variable outside of the loop, do you mean the last line of code? Thats what i dont get, how can it pick up a value from a variable that is not "listed" inside the function

Comment: This line `fahr = lower;`. That is inside the function right? The `while` loop is not a function if that is what you mean. That line and everything inside the loop are all within the same function.

Comment: You are right, but i still dont get why the value changes when i put it before printf.  Could somebody explain to me in details what happens as the program executes? Like how the value changes along the process. Im kinda confused with this as im trying to understand it.

Comment: Just run the program on paper line by line by writing down the variable values each line. Or better still, use a debugger to step thru the code line by line. That is the best way to understand what a program is doing.

Comment: I will do that, do you know by any chance how to enable the debugger in xcode? Everytime i hit the debugging tool button a message tells me "The scheme "C testing" is not configured for testing. Edit the scheme to enable testing, or cancel the action." But it says its enabled everywhere in the scheme?

Comment: strongly suggest you learn about the C programming syntax  Amongst other things, the statement: `fahr = lower;` is performed before the loop is entered  In general, `white space` (spaces, tabs, newlines) have little to do with what the program actually does

Comment: Im on it. i only thought since the program runs in the order its written in that the statement had to be before the final "function printf".